# Native module cannot be null for navigator.geolocation in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native application (`v0.42.0`) and I'm trying to use [Geolocation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/geolocation.html) but when I `navigator.geolocation` the following:

> Native module cannot be null.

Has anyone else ran into this issue or know how to diagnose the cause?

Comment: Knowing error : Due rewriting prototype you need to do this step, regards ;). https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that when using Cocoapods with React Native it is necessary to include `RCTGeolocation` in your `Podfile`:

```
pod 'React', :path => '../some/path/node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
  'Core',
  'RCTAnimation',
  'RCTImage',
  'RCTText',
  'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
  'RCTLinkingIOS',
  'ART',
  'RCTPushNotification',
  'RCTActionSheet',
  'RCTGeolocation'
]
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle! Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `RCTGeolocation` entry in your `Podfile`, if you are still getting the same error, check the following:

Make sure that the RCTGeolocation project is included in your Xcode project. If not, add it; it's located at `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Geolocation/RCTGeolocation.xcodeproj`

[image]

After adding the project, make sure to link to it too. Select the root project in the file explorer, select the correct target in TARGETS, then select the General tab. Because you've added the project in the previous step, you'll now be able to find and add `libRCTGeolocation.a`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:
`pod 'react-native-geolocation', path: '../node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation'` in your pod file.